# Variations of the Frobenius coin problem

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there a formula for solving problems such as: If there are n coin denominations x1,x2...xn that total p cents, what is the possible number of combinations of coins that total less than or equal to p.? Where n and p are positive real numbers, of course.

On a side note, wikipedia says: "There is an explicit formula for the Frobenius number when there are only two different coin denominations. If the number of coin denominations is three or more, no explicit formula is known; but, for any fixed number of coin denominations, there is an algorithm computing the Frobenius number in polynomial time (in the logarithms of the coin denominations forming an input)."

Does anyone know what the algorithm that wikipedia mentions is? I know it cannot be written explicitly and mathematically (as per wikipedia), but can anyone write it in another format?

Comment: Two points:  The Frobenius number F(c_1,...,c_n) is (when gcd(c_1,...,c_n)=1 ) the largest number which is not a nonnegative integral combination of the c's, and while the Wikipedia statement on the computational complexity is true, it is potentially misleading because the statement is likely to be misread as that the general problem is polynomial time solvable, which it currently is not.  I only know the dynamic programming method which builds up a list of permissible sums, from which the number F can be calculated.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.04.06

Comment: If you are looking for exact answers for more than two variables, neither the generating function nor Alfonsin's book will give you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the algorithm to compute the number of ways to change exactly $p$ cents (call it $n_p$) is to write down the generating function:

$G(z) = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{1-z^{x_i}},$ then $n_p$ is then simply the coefficient of $z^p.$ To get the answer to the question you are asking, just sum the coefficients from $0$ to $p.$

Answer (score 3):

You can find them in the book:

J.L. Ramirez Alfonsin.
The Diophantine Frobenius Problem.
Oxford Univ. Press 2005